# Abstracting a struct array

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am building a simple hard-coded csv parser that looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char * id;
    char * date;
} ROW;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Load a file that is of a known csv format
    // With fields separated by ","
    // And allow a max line length of 255 chars
    FILE * fp = fopen("test100k.csv", "r");
    char* FIELD_SEPARATOR = ",";
    char buffer[255];

    int row_num = 0;
    ROW row;
    ROW * rows = malloc(sizeof(row) * 120000);

    // The first line is the header so we can just skip it
    (void) fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {  

        // split the row
        char *token;
        token = row.id = strtok(buffer, FIELD_SEPARATOR);
        int num_sep_encountered = 1;

       while( token != NULL ) {
          token = strtok(NULL, FIELD_SEPARATOR);
          switch(num_sep_encountered)  {
              case 1: row.date = token;
          }
          num_sep_encountered ++;
       }

        printf("ID: %s | Date: %s\n", row.id, row.date);
        rows[row_num++] = row;
    }

}
```

I would like to change this so that I have a second struct called `ROWS` that looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    ROW * row;
    size_t size;
} ROWS;
```

How would I create and initialize this structs in the following three places:

```
// initialize it -- how to do this?
ROWS rows= malloc(sizeof(row) * 120000);

// how keep appending a ROW to the ROWS in the for loop?
rows->row = row

// how to set the size
rows.size = row_num
```

Comment: Keep in mind this allows a max line length of 253 or 254 depending on your platform. CR+LF+NUL or LF+NUL.

Comment: All your rows have pointers into the same `buffer` array, which you overwrite for each line you read. You need to use `strdup()` to make copies of them.

Comment: Isn't better to make your ROW structure a linked list?

Comment: @Barmar should it be `rows[row_num++] = strdup(row);` instead? Or where should I be changing that?

Comment: There isn't really enough information to answer. Does each row have individual size? Are sizes known at compile time? Do you need to both add and remove rows on the fly?

Comment: @Shared `row.id = strdup(strtok(buffer, FIELD_SEPARATOR));` and `row.date = strdup(token);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multidimensional initializations can be done like this:

```
const size_t no_rows = 120000;
const size_t row_size = 100;
ROWS *rows = malloc(sizeof(*rows) * no_rows);
for(size_t i=0; i<no_rows; i++) {
    rows[i].row = malloc(sizeof(*rows[0].row) * row_size);
    rows[i].size = row_size;
}
```

Remember to check the return value of `malloc`.